# Combine multiple rows (of one column) from mysql request into one field

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to gather the result of one query into one single field if possible.

The request is :

```
select  group_concat(col1) from table1
group by col3, col2
having count(*)>1
```

The result is like :

```
'123','124','125'
'123','125'
'126','127'
'123','127'
```

The result I'm looking for :

```
'123','124','125','123','125','126','127','123','127'
```

I tried to use again my `group_concat`, the concat fonction, or to use this whole query as a subquery without much success...

Comment: 'the whole query as a subquery' - can we see that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregation function, which you found. But you need to group the intermediate results again.

Apparently you have tried that, but since you didn't post your query, I'll give it to you:

```
select group_concat(col1intermediate) as col1total
from
  (select group_concat(col1) as col1intermediate
  from table1
  group by col3, col2
  having count(*)>1) as alias_subquery
```

I don't know why your own attempt failed. Maybe you forgot to add an alias (col1intermediate) to the aggregated column?

Comment: @Strawberry Yeah, I missed the 'count' part. Updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome... with this alias maping it worked ! I had to add an alias to the whole subquery though.